# CSS3 transition fade-out display property

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I was trying to make fade out transition with css3 but found out that display is not working with transitions.

i have a group object `<div id=groupID>` with `<h2>` title and `<div class='group'>` and i have onclick event bind to `<h2>` that should make group class to dissapear. i've tried to overcome display problem with `{opacity: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;}` This works fine as it has same effect as `{display:none}` BUT with

CSS

```
transition: all 2s ;
-webkit-transition: height 2s ease-out;
transition: opacity 2s ease-out ;
display: block;
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
```

JS

```
//collapse function
block.setStyle({opacity: 0});
block.setStyle({height: 0});

//expand function
block.setStyle({opacity: 1});
block.setStyle({height: 'auto'});
```

it doesn't do any animation on close but it fades in on reappearance. It just disappear instantly.

yes i need it in CSS3. NO, i can't use jQuery

any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Which browser are you testing with..can you create a fiddle and show us..

Answer (score 3):

Don't try and [transition to and from `auto`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3512194/8655).  It won't work.

You may be able to calculate the height in pixels of the element with JavaScript and use that in your `block.setStyle()` calls.